# How to compare date values (xsd:date) with years in SPARQL?

Tags: date, xsd, sparql

I created a SPARQL query to compare if the year of `dbo:birthDate` is different from the value of `dbo:birthYear`:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>  

Select distinct ?s ?vv1 ?vv2 where
  { ?s a dbo:Person ; dbo:birthDate ?v1 .
    ?s dbo:birthYear ?v2 . 
    bind(year(xsd:date(?v1)) as ?vv1) .
    bind(xsd:gYear(?v2) as ?vv2) .
    filter(?vv1 !=  ?vv2)
  }
```

I got the following answer:

```
                S                  vv1    vv2
<http://example.com/resource/1>   1993   1993
<http://example.com/resource/5>   1998   1993   
<http://example.com/resource/7>   1978   1978   
<http://example.com/resource/13>  1993   1993
```

The right answer is only the resource `5`, that has the year of `birthDate` equal to `1998` and the year of `birthYear` equal to `1993`. The answer shows that `vv1` and `vv2` have values to years without `" "`, and apparently both have the same type. So, I do not understand why SPARQL said that `vv1` and `vv2` in record `1`, for example, are distinct. I looked for how I can compare dates in SPARQL and I think my query is correct.

I tested this query using Fuseki 2.3.1

Examples of my instances:

```
@prefix dbo:   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix :      <http://example.com/resource/> .
@prefix dbp:   <http://dbpedia.org/property/> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml:   <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix mu:    <http://example.com/resource/> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

mu:1    a                dbo:Actor , 
                         dbo:Person , 
                         dbo:MusicalArtist , 
                         mu:MusicActor , 
                         owl:NamedIndividual ;
        dbo:birthDate    "1993-03-11"^^xsd:date ;
        dbo:birthYear    "1993" ;
        foaf:name        "John Joe"@en , 
                         "Joe, John"@en .

mu:5    a                <http://example.com/MusicActor> , 
                         dbo:Actor , 
                         dbo:Person , 
                         mu:MusicActor , 
                         owl:NamedIndividual ;
        dbo:birthDate    "1998-04-11" , 
                         "1998-04-11"^^xsd:date ;
        dbo:birthYear    "1993" ;
        foaf:name        "Barry Hannah"@en , 
                         "Barry B. Hannah"@en .

mu:7    a                dbo:Person , 
                         dbo:MusicalArtist , 
                         owl:NamedIndividual ;
        dbo:birthDate    "1978-05-11" , 
                         "1978-05-11"@en ;
        dbo:birthYear    "1978" ;
        foaf:name        "Helen Petty" , 
                         "Helen Petty"@en .
```

Anybody can, please, say why this is happing? I unfortunately have no idea. Any help will very appreciated!

Comment: I'm not convinced that `vv1` and `vv2` have the same type; in fact, your output suggests that they do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SPARQL year() function returns an integer, so you need to cast `?v2` to an integer:

```
SPARQL DISTINCT ?s ?vv1 ?vv2
WHERE {
   ?s a dbo:Person ; dbo:birthDate ?v1 .
   ?s dbo:birthYear ?v2 . 
   BIND(year(xsd:date(?v1)) as ?vv1) .
   BIND(xsd:integer(?v2) as ?vv2) .
   FILTER(?vv1 != ?vv2)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I believed that vv1 and vv2 were of the same type. I was wrong.